# How to change contenteditable to false in JCE?

Tags: joomla, contenteditable, joomla1.5, joomla-content-editor

I am using JCE in Joomla 1.5.x.

How can I configure the 'contenteditable ' value to 'false' only for the backend/administrator?

Comment: so you want that administrator cannot use the administrator options

Comment: [joomla-se] Stack Exchange was not available back when this question was posted, but all Joomla questions are now welcome there.